# expected primary-expression before "__typeof__"

Tags: c++, curl, influxdb

I am new to c++. I am trying a tiny piece of code to interact with a local instance of InfluxDB.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/curlver.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include <curl/mprintf.h>
#include <curl/multi.h>
#include <curl/stdcheaders.h>
#include <curl/system.h>
#include <curl/typecheck-gcc.h>

using namespace std;

bool createInfluxDB(char *url, char *data) {
  CURL *curl;

  curl = curl_easy_init();

  if(curl) {
    CURLcode res;
    /* What Content-type should i use?*/
    struct curl_slist* headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
    /*--data-urlencode*/
    char *urlencoded = curl_easy_escape(curl, data, int(strlen(data)));

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url); // Error here
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencoded);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE,     (long)strlen(urlencoded));

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /*omitted controls*/

    curl_free(urlencoded);
    curl_slist_free_all(headers);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }

  return(true);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   char *url = "http://localhost:8086/query";
   char *data = "q=CREATE DATABASE mydb";
   /* should i change data string to json?
      data = "{\"q\":\"CREATE DATABASE mydb\" }" */

   bool res = createInfluxDB(url, data);

   /*control result*/

   return(0);
}
```

When trying to build it, i get the following errors:

```
expected primary-expression before '__typeof__'
```

[extend list of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGQVB.png)

Any ideas where it might come from ?

I am working on codeblocks 16.01, using GCC compiler on Ubuntu.

Comment: On what line is the compiler giving you that error?

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the error message correctly? There seems to be `typeof` or `__typeof__`, but no `_typeof_`.

Comment: The compiler gives me an error at line 27

Comment: line 27: curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);

Comment: Is this line 27 of your source file? Isn't it line 27 of some included header file? What if you comment out all the code expect the inclusion of headers?

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes it is a line inside the source code, the IDE is actually showing me this with a red square at line 27 of my main code (it corresponds to the first call of curl_easy_setopt() ) However i have tried including only the headers as you mentioned and it compiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was due to curl library not being linked to the compiler. The correct way to fix this in Codeblocks editor:
Project>Build options..>"Linker settings" tab

Under Link libraries, click on add, type the library name on the popping window, click OK, click OK again. And reboot Codeblocks.